# VBA: Asynchronously manipulating PowerPoint slides from animated slide show

Tags: c#, .net, vba, multithreading, powerpoint

I have got a PowerPoint presentation, containing an animated image and a VBA script. The script calls a DLL written in C# which's purpose is it to add a number of slides and shapes into the presentation. Unfortunately, the DLL call immanently takes a few seconds, and as it works completely synchronously at the moment, the animated image is not updated during this time so the slide show looks lagging.

I thus wanted to make the DLL to work asynchronously, using a simple `ThreadStarter`:

```
public void DllEntrancePoint() {
    if (_isRefreshing)
        return;

    _isRefreshing = true;
    var threadStarter = new ThreadStart(DoAllTheWork);
    threadStarter += () => _isRefreshing = false;

    new Thread(threadStarter).Start();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I executed the DLL after this modification, its speed slowed down from a few seconds to a few minutes. Though the animated picture is displayed quite fluently now, this deceleration is not acceptable to me.

How can I run the DLL call in an appropriate time without the animation lagging? I suppose there is any multithreading overhead making the asynchronous call so slow. Is it still possible to achieve this aim? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting the code to launch the DLL in a dialog box.  Invoke the dialog box modelessly. The code in the dialog box should dismiss the dialog box after the DLL finishes its work.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right. What do you mean with a dialog box in a PowerPoint slide show? User should not see anything except of the slideshow. Further, how should I invoke it modelessly?

Comment: To  invoke it modelessly:  UserForm1.Show (vbModeless)  and if you position the dialog box off the screen the user won't see it.

Comment: I guess I understand your approach. So I declared a form and put my code in its `UserForm_Activate()`, but it  `UserForm1.Show (vbModeless)` still seems to run synchronously - animations are lagging. Should I use another event method instead of `Activate`?

Comment: Hmm. It may or may not work at all ... I only suggest this approach because it sometimes helps.  IAC, try in the form's Initialize routine, perhaps.

Comment: Appears not to work better on any way.